# I can't ask with any tech keyword as it is already asked

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, callback

I am trying to add more items into the actual array using **forEach** loop and loop should iterate based on the modified array. But somehow iteration is not occurring and control comes out once it loops through the original set of array elements before modification.

```
myArray.forEach(function(arrItem, index, actualArr){
  //My logic to calculate someOtherArray
  actualArr = actualArr.concat(someOtherArray);
});
```

I can't use any primitive loops like **for** or **while** because my code build tool does not allow me to. I also tried to modify "myArray" directly inside the call back function, but that did not help either.

Appreciate any help...!!

Comment: `my code build tool`
what tool is that?

Comment: “because my code build tool does not allow me to” stop using it then

Comment: I wish, but I can't stop using it.

Comment: Why not?︁︁︁︁︁︁︁